# p_value is 0 when I use scipy.stats.kstest() for large dataset

Tags: python, testing, scipy, normal-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have a unique series with there frequencies and want to know if they are from normal distribution so I did a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test using scipy.stats.kstest. Since, to my knowledge, the function takes only a list so I transform the frequencies to a list before I put it into the function. However, the result is weird since the pvalue=0.0

The histogram of the original data and my code are in the followings:
[Histogram of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uyyM.png)

```
[In]: frequencies = mp[['c','v']]

[In]: print frequencies
         c      v
31  3475.8   18.0
30  3475.6   12.0
29  3475.4   13.0
28  3475.2    8.0
20  3475.0   49.0
14  3474.8   69.0
13  3474.6   79.0
12  3474.4   78.0
11  3474.2   78.0
7   3474.0  151.0
6   3473.8  157.0
5   3473.6  129.0
2   3473.4  149.0
1   3473.2  162.0
0   3473.0  179.0
3   3472.8  145.0
4   3472.6  139.0
8   3472.4   95.0
9   3472.2  103.0
10  3472.0  125.0
15  3471.8   56.0
16  3471.6   75.0
17  3471.4   70.0
18  3471.2   70.0
19  3471.0   57.0
21  3470.8   36.0
22  3470.6   22.0
23  3470.4   20.0
24  3470.2   12.0
25  3470.0   23.0
26  3469.8   13.0
27  3469.6   17.0
32  3469.4    6.0

[In]: testData = map(lambda x: np.repeat(x[0], int(x[1])), frequencies.values)

[In]: testData = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(testData))

[In]: print len(testData)
2415

[In]: print np.unique(testData)
[ 3469.4  3469.6  3469.8  3470.   3470.2  3470.4  3470.6  3470.8  3471.
  3471.2  3471.4  3471.6  3471.8  3472.   3472.2  3472.4  3472.6  3472.8
  3473.   3473.2  3473.4  3473.6  3473.8  3474.   3474.2  3474.4  3474.6
  3474.8  3475.   3475.2  3475.4  3475.6  3475.8]

[In]: scs.kstest(testData, 'norm')
KstestResult(statistic=1.0, pvalue=0.0)
```

Thanks everyone at first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `'norm'` for your input will check if the distribution of your data is the same as `scipy.stats.norm.cdf` with default parameters: `loc=0, scale=1`.

Instead, you will need to fit a normal distribution to your data and *then* check if the data and the distribution are the same using the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, kstest
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

freqs = [[3475.8, 18.0], [3475.6, 12.0], [3475.4, 13.0], [3475.2, 8.0], [3475.0, 49.0],
    [3474.8, 69.0], [3474.6, 79.0], [3474.4, 78.0], [3474.2, 78.0], [3474.0, 151.0],
    [3473.8, 157.0], [3473.6, 129.0], [3473.4, 149.0], [3473.2, 162.0], [3473.0, 179.0],
    [3472.8, 145.0], [3472.6, 139.0], [3472.4, 95.0], [3472.2, 103.0], [3472.0, 125.0],
    [3471.8, 56.0], [3471.6, 75.0], [3471.4, 70.0], [3471.2, 70.0], [3471.0, 57.0],
    [3470.8, 36.0], [3470.6, 22.0], [3470.4, 20.0], [3470.2, 12.0], [3470.0, 23.0],
    [3469.8, 13.0], [3469.6, 17.0], [3469.4, 6.0]]

data = np.hstack([np.repeat(x,int(f)) for x,f in freqs])
loc, scale = norm.fit(data)
# create a normal distribution with loc and scale
n = norm(loc=loc, scale=scale)
```

Plot the fit of the norm to the data:

```
plt.hist(data, bins=np.arange(data.min(), data.max()+0.2, 0.2), rwidth=0.5)
x = np.arange(data.min(), data.max()+0.2, 0.2)
plt.plot(x, 350*n.pdf(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]

This not a terribly good fit, most due to the long tail on the left.  However, you can now run a proper Kolmogorov–Smirnov test using the `cdf` of the fitted normal distribution

```
kstest(data, n.cdf)
# returns:
KstestResult(statistic=0.071276854859734784, pvalue=4.0967451653273201e-11)
```

So we are still rejecting the null hypothesis of the distribution that produced the data being the same as the fitted distribution.

Comment: Thanks James. It really answered my questions. However, what is the n in the line plt.plot(x, 350*n.pdf(x)) and kstest(data, n.cdf)? If it is the function norm, as I tried, should it be plt.plot(x, 350*norm.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale)). Otherwise, it returns all 0 values.

Comment: oh, my mistake!  i left off a line, fixed.  `n` is the normal distribution given by `loc` and `scale`

Comment: Great. I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Jame, actually I am still confused on why you time 350 when you did the plot at plt.plot(x, 350*n.pdf(x)) ?

Comment: The `pdf` is normalized such that the integral over all of x equals 1.  I multiplied by 350 to make it's size comparable to the bars.

Comment: Did you determine 350 visually? Is there any ways I can determine it computationally? An approximate value should be fine.

Comment: Yes, it was just visually determined.  there are lots of ways to do it computationally.  the easiest is to normalize the histogram bars.